# stm32f4 discovery sample of using USB to communicate with pc or read/write pendrive using net micro framework

Tags: c#, .net-micro-framework, stm32f4

I cannot find any sample of using USB port of STM32F4 Discovery board in .NET Micro Framework. I'm trying to learn how to use USB port to send or write data. Where can I find such examples?

I've tried to make sample application based on https://guruce.com/blogpost/communicating-with-your-microframework-application-over-usb but it doesn't work.

This is part of my code sample:

```
using Microsoft.SPOT;
using Microsoft.SPOT.Hardware;
using Microsoft.SPOT.Hardware.UsbClient;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace MFConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        private const int WRITE_EP = 1;
        private const int READ_EP = 2;

        private static bool ConfigureUSBController(UsbController usbController)
        {
            bool bRet = false;

            // Create the device descriptor
            Configuration.DeviceDescriptor device = new Configuration.DeviceDescriptor(0xDEAD, 0x0001, 0x0100);
            device.bcdUSB = 0x110;
            device.bDeviceClass = 0xFF;     // Vendor defined class
            device.bDeviceSubClass = 0xFF;     // Vendor defined subclass
            device.bDeviceProtocol = 0;
            device.bMaxPacketSize0 = 8;        // Maximum packet size of EP0
            device.iManufacturer = 1;        // String #1 is manufacturer name (see string descriptors below)
            device.iProduct = 2;        // String #2 is product name
            device.iSerialNumber = 3;        // String #3 is the serial number

            // Create the endpoints
            Configuration.Endpoint writeEP = new Configuration.Endpoint(WRITE_EP, Configuration.Endpoint.ATTRIB_Bulk | Configuration.Endpoint.ATTRIB_Write);
            writeEP.wMaxPacketSize = 64;
            writeEP.bInterval = 0;

            Configuration.Endpoint readEP = new Configuration.Endpoint(READ_EP, Configuration.Endpoint.ATTRIB_Bulk | Configuration.Endpoint.ATTRIB_Read);
            readEP.wMaxPacketSize = 64;
            readEP.bInterval = 0;

            Configuration.Endpoint[] usbEndpoints = new Configuration.Endpoint[] { writeEP, readEP };

            // Set up the USB interface
            Configuration.UsbInterface usbInterface = new Configuration.UsbInterface(0, usbEndpoints);
            usbInterface.bInterfaceClass = 0xFF; // Vendor defined class
            usbInterface.bInterfaceSubClass = 0xFF; // Vendor defined subclass
            usbInterface.bInterfaceProtocol = 0;

            // Create array of USB interfaces
            Configuration.UsbInterface[] usbInterfaces = new Configuration.UsbInterface[] { usbInterface };

            // Create configuration descriptor
            Configuration.ConfigurationDescriptor config = new Configuration.ConfigurationDescriptor(500, usbInterfaces);

            // Create the string descriptors
            Configuration.StringDescriptor manufacturerName = new Configuration.StringDescriptor(1, Consts.MANUFACTURER);
            Configuration.StringDescriptor productName = new Configuration.StringDescriptor(2, Consts.PRODUCT_NAME);
            Configuration.StringDescriptor serialNumber = new Configuration.StringDescriptor(3, Consts.SERIAL_NO);
            Configuration.StringDescriptor displayName = new Configuration.StringDescriptor(4, Consts.DISPLAYED_NAME);
            Configuration.StringDescriptor friendlyName = new Configuration.StringDescriptor(5, Consts.FRENDLY_NAME);

            // Create the final configuration
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.descriptors = new Configuration.Descriptor[]
            {
            device,
            config,
            manufacturerName,
            productName,
            serialNumber,
            displayName,
            friendlyName
            };

            try
            {
                // Set the configuration
                usbController.Configuration = configuration;
                if (UsbController.ConfigError.ConfigOK != usbController.ConfigurationError)
                    throw new ArgumentException();
                // If all ok, start the USB controller.
                bRet = usbController.Start();
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                Debug.Print(Consts.CONFIG_ERR + usbController.ConfigurationError.ToString());
            }
            return bRet;
        }

        private static string GetCommand(byte[] data)
        {
            return new string(Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(data));
        }

        private static byte[] GetDataToSend(Reading data, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializer.Serialize(data));
        }

        private static void UsbMainLoop(UsbStream usbStream, AnalogInput supplyInput, AnalogInput dataInput, OutputPort recievingDataIndicator, OutputPort seindingDataIndicator, JsonSerializer dataSerializer)
        {
            byte[] readData = new byte[100];
            for (;;)
            {
                recievingDataIndicator.Write(true);
                int bytesRead = usbStream.Read(readData, 0, readData.Length);
                recievingDataIndicator.Write(false);
                if (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    string command = GetCommand(readData);
                    switch (command)
                    {
                        case "READ":
                            seindingDataIndicator.Write(true);
                            byte[] dataToSend = GetDataToSend(Reading.GetReading(supplyInput, dataInput), dataSerializer);
                            usbStream.Write(dataToSend, 0, dataToSend.Length);
                            seindingDataIndicator.Write(false);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static UsbController CheckSupportAndAccessibility(UsbController[] usbControllers, out string message)
        {
            UsbController usbController = null;
            if (0 == usbControllers.Length)
            {
                message = Consts.USB_NOT_SUPPORTED;
            }
            else
            {
                bool foundedFreeUsb = false;
                foreach (UsbController controller in usbControllers)
                {
                    if (UsbController.PortState.Stopped == controller.Status)
                    {
                        usbController = controller;
                        foundedFreeUsb = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (foundedFreeUsb)
                {
                    message = string.Empty;
                }
                else
                {
                    message = Consts.NO_FREE_USB;
                }
            }
            return usbController;
        }

        private static void OtherMainProgramLoop()
        {
            AnalogInput temperature0 = new AnalogInput(Cpu.AnalogChannel.ANALOG_0);
            AnalogInput supply0 = new AnalogInput(Cpu.AnalogChannel.ANALOG_1);
            double t0, r0, z0;
            while (true)
            {
                z0 = supply0.Read() * 3;
                r0 = Reading.GetRt(z0, temperature0.Read() * z0);
                t0 = Reading.GetTemp(r0);
                Debug.Print("Supply:" + z0.ToString() + "[V]");
                Debug.Print("Rt:" + r0.ToString() + "[Ohm]");
                Debug.Print("Temperature:" + t0.ToString() + "[^C]");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            UsbController[] controllers = UsbController.GetControllers();
            string msg;
            UsbController usbController = CheckSupportAndAccessibility(controllers, out msg);
            if (null == usbController)
            {
                Debug.Print(msg);
                OtherMainProgramLoop();
                //return;
            }
            else
            {
                UsbStream usbStream = null;
                try
                {
                    if (ConfigureUSBController(usbController))
                        usbStream = usbController.CreateUsbStream(WRITE_EP, READ_EP);
                    else
                        throw new Exception();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Debug.Print(Consts.USB_CREATE_STREAM_ERR + usbController.ConfigurationError.ToString());
                    OtherMainProgramLoop();
                    //return;
                }

                AnalogInput temperatureSource = new AnalogInput(Cpu.AnalogChannel.ANALOG_0);
                AnalogInput supplySource = new AnalogInput(Cpu.AnalogChannel.ANALOG_1);
                OutputPort ledGreen = new OutputPort((Cpu.Pin)60, false);
                OutputPort ledYellow = new OutputPort((Cpu.Pin)61, false);

                UsbMainLoop(usbStream, supplySource, temperatureSource, ledYellow, ledGreen, new JsonSerializer());
                usbStream.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hope this helps: https://staceyw1.wordpress.com/2011/03/18/connect-com-ports-to-fez-via-usb/